# Spark-submit fails with return code 13 for example of wordCount

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

My spark-submit command is :

```
spark-submit --class com.sundogsoftware.spark.WordCountBetterDataset --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster SparkCourse.jar
```

And for defining the sparkSession, i use this :

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .master("spark://youness:7077")
  .appName("WordCount")
  .getOrCreate()
```

but at the end, my job fails with return code 13.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the `master` unset in the code. It is preferable to set it later when you issue `spark-submit` (`spark-submit --master yarn-client ...`) and you are already doing that above. Just remove `.master("spark://youness:7077")` from your code.